# VB WebBrowser Name in connection Stats

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, browser, webbrowser-control

If you have a VB.Net app that connects to a website. What browser does it show as that ip address used to connect?

Basically will is show up as a VB.net application when the website admin runs stats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebBrowser control is a hosted instance of IE.
As such, it sends IE's `User-Agent`.

You can see this in Fiddler.

Comment: So in short, no way to tell interactions are automated with a website, only that the interaction was potentially through IE?

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD: Probably not.